# jQuery inside the backend of a joomla module is not working

Tags: joomla-2.5, development, php, module, jquery

This is the current state of a module I'm trying to make. From the backend I select some names , and the photos of that names and in the frontend names and photos i selected will get printed at index page.
The module's base functionality is working really fine, the only thing is that I want to add 2 more elements: *Counter* and *Selected*.

*Counter*: Is the number of names the user selected.A jquery script that will parse the count of selected names from first field and will show the number in a text box.

*Selected*: Will be a textarea with every name selected.One More jquery script that will parse every selected name and will show em in a textarea.

I have semi-written the code for the counter field ( I must have done something wrong ) , and I would like someone to help me findout why the script isnt working.

[image]

Codes:

Jquery script:

```
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                  var count = $("#jform_params_foreignmanuf :selected").length;
                  return count;
              });
</script>
```

manulist.php (dropdownlist/custom field)

```
<?php

defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;
JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');
class JFormFieldManulist extends JFormFieldList
{

        protected $type = 'Manulist';


        protected function getOptions()
        {

         $db= JFactory::getDbo();
         $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('*');
        $query->from('#__virtuemart_manufacturers_en_gb');
        $db->setQuery($query);
         $items = $db->loadObjectList();
         $options = array();
         if ($items)
         {
          foreach($items as $item)
          {
            $options[] = JHtml::_('select.option', $item->virtuemart_manufacturer_id , $item->mf_name,$item->slug);
          }
         }
         $options = array_merge(parent::getOptions(), $options);
         JHtml::_('script', JUri::root() . 'modules/mod_manufacturers/js/js.js');
         return $options;

        }


}
```

countermanu.php(text field of selected records)

```
<?php

defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;
JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('Text');
class JFormFieldManulist extends JFormFieldText
{

        protected $type = 'Countermanu';


        protected function getOptions()
        {

        $doc = JDocument::getDocument();
       $js = '
             jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                 var count = $("#jform_params_foreignmanuf :selected").length;
                 return count;
             });
      ';
       $doc->addScriptDeclaration($js);
        JHtml::_('script', JUri::root() . 'modules/mod_manufacturers/js/js.js');

        }


}
```

Edit:
What i actually need is someone help me to find out why the jquery script isnt running

Comment: Please specify: What is the non working part? What your code fails to do?

Comment: The counter field is just blank as shown in the picture, so it means my methodology of adding jquery in the backend fails somewhere and i dont know what i do wrong as i never tried it before today.

Comment: Check the console log in your browser for any errors

Comment: How i actually do that? I read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console.log 
but i cant understand what i have to do.
My script call syntax/function is ok ?

Comment: Simply press `F12`, go to the **Console** tab, then refresh the page. If there are any errors, they will appear in red

Comment: Edited my question to be more specific. 
@Lodder i get no errors at all.